# create an aws ec2 instance on centos 7 through ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I created a playbook *aws.yml* and want to run it over my local host

```
---
-  hosts: webserver

-  vars:
      region: ap-south-1
      instance_type: t2.micro
      ami: ami-005956c5f0f757d37  # Amazon linux LTS
      keypair: ansible # pem file name

-  tasks:

    -  ec2:
         key_name: "{{ ansible }}"
         group: ansible  # security group name
         instance_type: "{{ t2.micro }}"
         image: "{{ ami-005956c5f0f757d37 }}"
         wait: true
         wait_timeout: 500
         region: "{{ ap-south-1 }}"
         count: 1  # default
         count_tag:
            Name: Prod-Instance
         instance_tags:
            Name: Prod-Instance
         vpc_subnet_id: subnet-00efd068
         assign_public_ip: yes
```

Content of the host file */etc/ansible/hosts*

```
[web]
localhost
```

When I try to run my *aws.yml*, it gives the below error

```
[root@localhost ~]# ansible-playbook  aws.yml

PLAY [web] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Your playbook and your hosts group name does not match.

In *aws.yml*

```
- hosts: webserver
```

And in */etc/ansible/hosts*

```
[web]
```

You should either change your *aws.yml* playbook to read

```
- hosts: web
```

**Or** your hosts file */etc/ansible/hosts* to read

```
[webserver]
```

Comment: I just change the entries in /etc/ansible/host    

[localhost]
localhost

Comment: when i just try to remove the - s from the task and var it give the below error Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find the expected '-' indicator The error appears to be in '/root/aws.yml': line 5, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem. The offending line appears to be:
  vars:
  ^ here

Comment: Please help me to find the exact problem

Comment: Thanks Jack, after some changes, this is the new error i got. TASK [ec2] ******fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/aws.yml': line 9, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - ec2:\n    ^ here\n"}

Comment: ---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      region: ap-south-1
      instance_type: t2.micro
      ami: ami-005956c5f0f757d37  # Amazon linux LTS
      keypair: newkey
      image: ami-005956c5f0f757d37
  tasks:
  - ec2:
      key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
      group: ansible  # security group name
      instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
      image: "{{ image }}"
      wait: true
      wait_timeout: 500
  region: ap-south-1,count: 1  # default  count_tag:Name: Dev-Instance instance_tags: Name: Dev-Instance vpc_subnet_id: subnet-00efd068  assign_public_ip: yes delegate_to: localhost

Comment: Thanks Guys, It's working fine after correcting the variable limits

Answer (score 0):

Too many `-`s.  Remove the ones in front of `tasks` and `vars`.

Also, use `delegate_to: localhost` on the `ec2` task:

```
---
- hosts: webserver
  vars:
      region: ap-south-1
      instance_type: t2.micro
      ami: ami-005956c5f0f757d37  # Amazon linux LTS
      keypair: ansible # pem file name
  tasks:
  - ec2:
      key_name: "{{ ansible }}"
      group: ansible  # security group name
      instance_type: "{{ t2.micro }}"
      image: "{{ ami-005956c5f0f757d37 }}"
      wait: true
      wait_timeout: 500
      region: "{{ ap-south-1 }}"
      count: 1  # default
      count_tag:
        Name: Prod-Instance
      instance_tags:
        Name: Prod-Instance
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-00efd068
      assign_public_ip: yes
    delegate_to: localhost
```